# Check the MYSQL manual for correct syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have following MYSQL syntax but when I am running it , it gives me error to check the MYSQL manual for correct syntax.

The MYSQL query is:

```
SELECT `listings`.sid FROM listings 
        LEFT JOIN `listings_properties` `lp` ON `lp`.`object_sid` = `listings`.`sid` AND `lp`.`id` = \'ClosingDate\'
        WHERE (expiration_date < NOW() OR `lp`.`value` <= NOW()) AND active = 1
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here AND `lp`.`id` = \'ClosingDate\'

Comment: what is the error? copy and paste it. You should also paste where you are using it from the PHP code

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'ClosingDate\' WHERE (expiration_date < NOW() OR `lp`.`value` <= NOW()) AND ' at line 2

Comment: try by remove both backslash (\\) on '\'ClosingDate\'

Comment: Three columns Here. 1- Expiration Date, 2-Closing Date, and 3-Active Column.

I want to select those rows where Expiration or Closing Date (dates) value are equal or less than current date and Active column value is also equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.`sid` FROM `listings` a LEFT JOIN `listings_properties` b 
ON (b.`object_sid` = a.`sid` AND b.`id` = 'ClosingDate')
WHERE (a.`expiration_date` < NOW() OR b.`value` <= NOW()) AND a.`active` = 1
```

No need to escape `'`

Answer (score 1):

try by remove both backslash () on '\'ClosingDate\' to be come:

```
SELECT `listings`.sid FROM listings 
LEFT JOIN `listings_properties` `lp` 
   ON `lp`.`object_sid` = `listings`.`sid` 
   AND `lp`.`id` = 'ClosingDate'
WHERE (expiration_date < NOW() 
   OR `lp`.`value` <= NOW()) AND active = 1
```

Comment: I have Three columns Here. 1- Expiration Date, 2-Closing Date, and 3-Active Column. I want to select those rows where Expiration or Closing Date (dates) value are equal or less than current date and Active column value is also equal to 1

Comment: Does it doing the above thing?

Comment: can you post here your table schema? (both listings and listings_properties).

do you want to show record with those three columns? the quesry just shown confusing on this part: AND `lp`.`id` = 'ClosingDate'.

Answer (score 1):

here is the error

```
LEFT JOIN `listings_properties` `lp` ON `lp`.`object_sid` = `listings`.`sid` AND `lp`.`id` = \'ClosingDate\'
```

should be

```
  LEFT JOIN `listings_properties` `lp` ON `lp`.`object_sid` = `listings`.`sid` AND `lp`.`id` = 'ClosingDate'
```

and whole query

```
SELECT a.`sid` FROM `listings` a LEFT JOIN `listings_properties` b 
ON (b.`object_sid` = a.`sid` AND b.`id` = 'ClosingDate')
WHERE (a.`expiration_date` < NOW() OR b.`value` <= NOW()) AND a.`active` = 1
```